# Trying to load png from assembly

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to write helper assembly with a helper class with a static method that loads Image from resource.

Here is the code

```
        public static BitmapImage GetImageFromResource(Assembly assembly, string file)
       {
        BitmapImage src = new BitmapImage();
        src.BeginInit();
        src.UriSource = new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/" + assembly.GetName().Name + @";component/" + file, UriKind.Absolute);
        src.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
        src.EndInit();

        return src;
       }
```

I am trying to call this from a different assembly which has the png file with Build Action as Resource (Have also tried, Embedded Resource and Content)

I am getting the following error

```
Additional information: Cannot locate resource 'coffee.png'.
```

What am I doing wrong ? Also, the C is uppercase, but somehow in error message it appears that it is trying to locate coffee.png instead of Coffee.png.

Anybody knows what am I missing here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Make sure** that the assembly that you are loading has the updated `dll`. Try doing a `rebuild` on your `class library` file that has the `image`. What you have should work. It is only the matter that the `image` is not really in the `dll`.